# For which rings $R$ is $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb Z}(R)$ isomorphic to $R$ (that is, the only endomorpisms are the multiplication maps)?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, group-isomorphism, monoid, ring-isomorphism

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a commutative ring. It is a well-known fact that the ring of $R$-module endomorphisms of $R$, that is $(\operatorname{End}_R(R),+,\circ)$, is isomorphic to $(R,+,\cdot)$. Clearly, every module homomorphism is a homomorphism of abelian groups (and thus a $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism), and thus we have $\operatorname{End}_R(R) \subseteq \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb Z}(R)$. In other words: The map $R \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb Z}(R)$ given by $r\mapsto(x\mapsto rx)$ is an injective ring homomorphism. My question is: Under which conditions on $R$ is this map also surjective?

[According to the comments, the following question can be answered by "no": Are rings $R$ where $(R,+)$ is cyclic the only examples?]

Comment: You explicitly say you're going to write $\mathrm{End}(R)$ and then all we see is  $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb Z(R)$... they're meant to be the same right?

Comment: What I originally wanted to emphasize is $\operatorname{End}_{\text{bla}}(R) =  \operatorname{End}_{\text{bla}}(R,+)$ to emphasize the additive property being preserved, but that seems to be clear anyway because the sum of two ring endomorphisms is never a ring homomorphism (unless $R$ is the trivial ring). Thus I've edited my question to make it more direct.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: If $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ is an epimorphism, then any abelian group endomorphism of $R$ is in fact an $R$-module endomorphism. Non-surjective epimorphisms do exist (think $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$, for example).

Comment: Indeed, every group endomorphism of $\mathbb Q$ is a $\mathbb Q$-module endomorphism of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: Is that condition also necessary? If I understand it correctly, the map $R \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb Z}(R)$ given by $r \mapsto (x \mapsto rx)$ is an injective ring homomorphism. I'm looking for conditions under which this map is also surjective, right?